# Symfony 2.7 QueryBuilder - Join Unneeded Entity Association as an Empty Reference to Attach It's Assocations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony 2.7, is it possible to use the Doctrine `queryBuilder` to return an arrayCollection of all `foo` entities, that has joined another entity that isn't directly associated (they share a middle relationship), without loading that middle entity? So for example:

```
$foo = {
    'bar' => {
        'baz' => { .. baz entity .. }
    },
    'barId'
}
$baz = {
    'barId'
}
```

I want to access the `baz` entity, but I do not want to load the entire `bar` entity (because a postLoad listener on `bar` will trigger unnecessarily and I don't need that data or extra database calls). Essentially the `bar` entity just needs to be an empty ***Reference***, which contains an association with the `baz` entity that I really want.

Of course it is possible to join the `baz` entity without the `bar` entity, but the queryBuilder result will not be a `foo` entity, it becomes a useless array. What I want is an entity with the regular structure.

So this simple query works to join everything correctly:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('foo')
    ->leftJoin('AcmeUberBundle:Baz', 'baz', 'WITH', 'baz.barId=foo.barId')
    ->addSelect('baz');
$foo = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**Problem:** 
This correctly joins everything, but the results are a basic array like:

```
array(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => baz
    [2] => baz
    [3] => foo
    [4] => baz
    [5] => foo
    [6] => baz
    [7] => baz
    [8] => baz
)
```

Where each `baz` that shares the same `barId` as `foo` is returned in a row. I suppose I could parse that, but it's less than ideal. I'd like `foo` entities.

**Ideal Solution:**
What I would like is a way to tell the queryBuilder to `select` a ***REFERENCE*** to bar and join baz on bar (similar to how you can create a doctrine reference in PHP so that you have an entity that is just populated by an ID). So the final `foo` array collection that is returned has $foo->bar->baz and `bar` is like an empty room you just walk through to get to `baz` (since you don't want any of the data in `bar`).

Comment: Bfeore `leftJoin` try to set `->select("baz")` and remove the `addSelect()` method.

Comment: It's possible that partial objects may help: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html but be sure to read the caveats carefully.  I suspect your listener will still get kicked off.  You could create a different entity manager without the listeners.

Comment: @StivenLlupa changing the order of when you select doesn't change how doctrine fetches and populates the entity. It selects baz, but it's an incomplete entity so it can't return an entity with associations, it returns arrays of the individual entities.

Comment: It sounds like partials are a bad idea in practice. I wrote a function that just parses the array of returned objects and constructs an entity with associations. I made it add `bar` as a Reference only (and it doesn't trigger the entity listener then). But the problem is, as soon as I add `baz` as an association to `bar`, doctrine hydrates the entire `bar` entity :D so this whole method doesn't work. I solved the problem by just making a non-persisted property on `foo` that I can add `baz` results in the parser (instead of the empty `bar` Reference. So That works just fine.

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer My intention was so that you explicitly say Select only `baz` entities since your query builder already selects `foo` by default.